# Web Based Architecture of an Old Windows based application

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, n-tier-architecture

We are in process of re designing an old windows client server based application to web based application.
This application is built in C# using Remoting and WCF. On client side its Windows and WPF.

My Queries

1. What all concepts should be taken care when we make this application web based?
2. What design patterns should be followed for Web Based Architecture?
3. In WCF part we are using Net TCP Binding which can be easily migrated to HttpBinding, but I am more concern over Remoting, will it able to Serve the purpose, means can Remoting serve the purpose when Http calls are being made?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably merge "remoting" with wcf and use httpbinding endpoint. font-end you could decide to use MVC pattern which will give you a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer your question with a question but: From an architecture or business point of view, why would you want to do this?

Your original application uses Remoting, which does not work over the Internet, therefore I am assuming that this is an internal application.

A web application would have the following tiers:

- The presentation which runs on the browser
- The Web Server which sends the pages to the browser
- The application server which would host your WCF services
- The database server

As you see the web application in the browser does not call the services directly (unless you use REST based services)